# Parsing file with sscanf

Tags: printf, stm32, scanf

I am currently trying to parse file with contents something like this using sscanf:

```
param1 = value1
...
param5=value5
...
paramn = valuen
```

I need to extract values by param name.
For example:

```
sscanf((char*)rtext, "param5=%s", label)
```

I am trying to get "value5" into string variable "label".
This example returns 0 coincidences. I have tried various specificators with no luck. Looks like this not working because there is another symbols including new line before "param5". How to tell sscanf to skip this until "param5" will be found? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read file line by line until you will get the successful scan.